# ORA-01722: invalid number in Case statement

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g, group-by

Hi I am new to oracle database.In the query below,`ZERO_BAL_CODE` is `varchar2` datatype. I tried to write a case statement, but its throwing an error stating that `"ORA-01722: invalid number"`.  Help me to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

```
  SELECT id_loan,
         MAX (TO_NUMBER (delinq_status)) AS delinq_status,
         MAX (loan_age) AS loan_age,
         MAX (zero_bal_code) AS zero_bal_code,
         MAX (vintage) AS vintage,
         MIN (actual_loss) AS actual_loss,
         MIN (NULLIF (current_upb, 0)) AS current_upb,
         loan_type
    FROM (SELECT master_copy.id_loan,
                 loan_age,
                 master_copy.vintage,
                 delinq_status,
                 zero_bal_code,
                 master_copy.actual_loss,
                 current_upb,
                 CASE
                    WHEN (zero_bal_code IN (3)) THEN 'default_foreclosure'
                    WHEN (zero_bal_code IN (1)) THEN 'prepaid'
                    WHEN (zero_bal_code IN (6)) THEN 'default_reo'
                    WHEN (zero_bal_code IN (9)) THEN 'active'
                 END
                    AS loan_type
            FROM master_copy
                 INNER JOIN (SELECT id_loan FROM master_copy) a
                    ON master_copy.id_loan = a.id_loan) b
GROUP BY id_loan, loan_type;
```

Comment: Try to add quotes and check  Example:('1')

Comment: So the broad answer is: this is what happens when we have a data model which stores numeric values in string columns. No matter how bulletproof we may think the application's validation the lessons of history are that our data will inevitably become corrupt.

Comment: @Raghavi - this is almost always a **data issue**. There are some records which have non-numeric values in columns where you expect them to have only numeric values. If you dispute this please post table structure and some sample records which produce this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't post table description, so - to me - this looks suspicious:

```
MAX (TO_NUMBER (delinq_status)) AS delinq_status,
```

If `DELINQ_STATUS` column's datatype was `NUMBER`, you wouldn't have to `TO_NUMBER` it. If it is `VARCHAR2`, then someone might have entered 'ABC1234' into it which would cause `TO_NUMBER` function to fail.

So, if you run this, what is the result?

```
select max(to_number(delinq_status)) from master_copy
```

---

As of missing single quotes in `CASE`: id depends on column contents. If it is a "number", single quotes aren't necessary although column's datatype is `VARCHAR2` (but would make a *good practice*; on the other hand, if column contains *only* numbers, why isn't its datatype `NUMBER`?):

```
SQL> create table test (zero_bal_code varchar2(1));

Table created.

SQL> insert into test values ('1');

1 row created.

SQL> select case when zero_bal_code in (3) then 'default_foreclosure'
  2              else 'unknown'
  3         end loan_type
  4  from test;

LOAN_TYPE
-------------------
unknown
```

However, if there's something different than "numbers", then single quotes matter:

```
SQL> insert into test values ('B');

1 row created.

SQL> select case when zero_bal_code in (3) then 'default_foreclosure'
  2              else 'unknown'
  3         end loan_type
  4  from test;
ERROR:
ORA-01722: invalid number



no rows selected

SQL> select case when zero_bal_code in ('3') then 'default_foreclosure'
  2              else 'unknown'
  3         end loan_type
  4  from test;

LOAN_TYPE
-------------------
unknown
unknown

SQL>
```

---

By the way, what you wrote doesn't make much sense; are codes for *prepaid, default_reo and active* really `1`? All of them? How will you distinguish which is which?

```
             CASE
                WHEN (zero_bal_code IN (3)) THEN 'default_foreclosure'
                WHEN (zero_bal_code IN (1)) THEN 'prepaid'
                WHEN (zero_bal_code IN (1)) THEN 'default_reo'
                WHEN (zero_bal_code IN (1)) THEN 'active'
             END
```

Comment: Sorry.. default_reo is 6 and active is 9. select max(to_number(delinq_status)) from master_copy returns invalid number.

Comment: That means that you should first fix DELINQ_STATUS column values. It must not contain anything but numbers (if you want to apply TO_NUMBER to it).

Comment: SELECT ID_LOAN,max(to_number(DELINQ_STATUS)) as DELINQ_STATUS,max(loan_age) AS LOAN_AGE,max(ZERO_BAL_CODE) 
as ZERO_BAL_CODE,max(vintage) as vintage,
min(ACTUAL_LOSS) as actual_loss,MIN(NULLIF(current_upb,0)) as current_upb ,'prepaid' as loan_type
FROM
(SELECT m.ID_LOAN,LOAN_AGE,m.vintage,DELINQ_STATUS,ZERO_BAL_CODE,m.ACTUAL_LOSS,current_upb 
FROM master_copy m INNER JOIN (SELECT ID_LOAN FROM master_copy WHERE ZERO_BAL_CODE IN (1))A ON m.ID_LOAN= A.ID_LOAN) B
group by ID_LOAN)); but this is working fine. here I try to combine as a case statement it throws an error.

Comment: How many rows did that query return? If you use some GUI, they usually return a couple of hundred rows - not all of them. So, if there's no error in that data set, query will run "successfully" (hiding the error). If you navigate to the end of rows, you will probably hit it. Anyway: DELINQ_STATUS must not contain anything but numbers. Enclose ZERO_BAL_CODE values into single quotes.

Comment: It tried with single quotes also.. still the same error.

Comment: That's not enough, if you didn't **make sure that DELINQ_STATUS contains only numbers**.

Comment: It contains '0'

Comment: Aha. Yet another possibility: **NULLIF**. What is CURRENT_UPB's datatype? If it is a VARCHAR2, then you should enclose 0 into single quotes (as datatypes should match): `NULLIF (current_upb, '0')`

Comment: Current_upb is a number. In the above case enclosing '0' , it throws this error "ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got CHAR"

Comment: Apply TO_NUMBER function to convert a CHAR to a NUMBER (if you can). Or vice versa - apply TO_CHAR to convert a NUMBER to a CHAR.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with ':

```
  SELECT id_loan,
         MAX (TO_NUMBER (delinq_status)) AS delinq_status,
         MAX (loan_age) AS loan_age,
         MAX (zero_bal_code) AS zero_bal_code,
         MAX (vintage) AS vintage,
         MIN (actual_loss) AS actual_loss,
         MIN (NULLIF (current_upb, 0)) AS current_upb,
         loan_type
    FROM (SELECT master_copy.id_loan,
                 loan_age,
                 master_copy.vintage,
                 delinq_status,
                 zero_bal_code,
                 master_copy.actual_loss,
                 current_upb,
                 CASE
                    WHEN (zero_bal_code IN ('3')) THEN 'default_foreclosure'
                    WHEN (zero_bal_code IN ('1')) THEN 'prepaid'
                    WHEN (zero_bal_code IN ('1')) THEN 'default_reo'
                    WHEN (zero_bal_code IN ('1')) THEN 'active'
                 END
                    AS loan_type
            FROM master_copy
                 INNER JOIN (SELECT id_loan FROM master_copy) a
                    ON master_copy.id_loan = a.id_loan) b
GROUP BY id_loan, loan_type;
```